# is it ok to say "from diagnosing to treatment to follow up"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, syntactic-analysis

what i want to express is

> Blockquote

from diagnosis to treatment to follow up

> Blockquote

.i want to express it in a way that reader feels that its a continuous and long term process.
**diagnosis - treatment - follow up**
Please suggest me a proper way to express this.
thanks in advance

Comment: As this is a site on **English Language & Usage**, ***PLEASE*** use standard English capitalisation, punctuation, etc. when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the parallelism here it would be most common to express this as:

"From diagnosis to treatment to follow-up, the good people at Acme Medical Insurance Corporation treated me well."